# Add click function to a cell (game of life)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to add an eventListener too my grid, so if I'm gonna click a cell it will turn into black and gets the value true. How can I change the cells value into true?

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 800;

    const resolution = 20;
    const horizontal = canvas.width / resolution;
    const vertikal = canvas.height / resolution;

    function buildGrid() {
        return new Array(horizontal).fill(null)
            .map(()=> new Array(vertikal).fill(null)
                .map(function(){choose();})); //Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    }


function choose () {
    canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an array which holds the state of each cell (false/true). A two-dimensional array is the best choice for this use-case.

```
var grid = new Array();
for (var a = 0; a < vertikal; a++) {
  grid[a] = new Array();
  for (var b = 0; b < horizontal; b++) {
    grid[a].push(false);
  }
}
```

This creates such an array and prepopulates each element with **false**.

Each cell's size is controlled by the variable **resolution**.
Inside the callback function for the click event listener you've attached to the canvas, we can figure out which cell we've clicked by using this formula:
**floor(mousePosition/resolution)**

A simple example: We know that  each cell is 20 pixels. If the user clicked at x=123, we get 123/20 = 6.15 == 6

The same needs to be done for the vertical mouse click of course.

Now we can simply toggle a cell's state using this:

```
grid[cellY][cellX] = !grid[cellY][cellX];
```

So if the value of the element at cellX;cellY has been false it becomes true and vice versa.

Finally we need to loop over the array and update the canvas accordingly.

Here's the full sample. (click on 'Run code snippet' and click anywhere inside the canvas to toggle a cell)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 800;

const resolution = 20;
var horizontal = canvas.width / resolution;
var vertikal = canvas.height / resolution;

var grid = new Array();
for (var a = 0; a < vertikal; a++) {
  grid[a] = new Array();
  for (var b = 0; b < horizontal; b++) {
    grid[a].push(false);
  }
}

function updateGrid() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var a = 0; a < vertikal; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < horizontal; b++) {
      if (grid[a][b]) {
        ctx.fillRect(b * resolution, a * resolution, resolution, resolution);
      }
    }
  }

}
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var cellX = Math.floor((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / resolution);
  var cellY = Math.floor((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / resolution);
  grid[cellY][cellX] = !grid[cellY][cellX];
  updateGrid();
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```